# I want to have nested todos in Sample Todo Application for ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm new to ember.js.
Im trying to buid this sample todo app.(http://emberjs.com/examples/todos/)

I have a quesition.

I want to have nested tasks appear as shown below.

- TASK A

  - task a
  - task b
- TASK B

  - task a
- TASK C

How can I implement this?

I read ember.js Doc(http://emberjs.com/documentation/),but I dont think this document provide enough information to accomplish what I want.

I would be very appreciated if you could give me some hints for this!!

Thanks,

Comment: It's "want to", not "wanna".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "I wanna go-o-o-o..."

Comment: You wanna use angularjs instead

Answer (score 1):

I would have started by updating the model to meet [the composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), then update the handlebar view to be able to reflect the child views (of similar type).